# Assistance with translation in some lyrics

Tags: translation, syntax, song-lyrics

> 寄せかえる波を見ていた　母の遠いまなざし

I'm used to sentences ending in a verb so I assume it could be translated as "Was watching the waves surge back". My mother's distant gaze." as separate phrases.

Am I right to say "My mother’s distant gaze was watching the waves surge back."

Similarly,

> 幼い私は　強く強く握った
>
> 顔をしかめて　母が力なく言う 「痛いよ」

"The childish me grabbed strongly. My mother frowned and said without strength, 'It hurts'"

I think that's incorrect as I'm unsure of 'who's doing what'.

Answer (score 2):

寄せかえる波を見ていた　母の遠いまなざし
The distant gaze of my mother, who was watching the waves surge back.

幼い私 literally means "young I".
It refers to the speaker when he was a child.

So the translation becomes:
幼い私は　強く強く握った
As a child, I would grab strongly.